# Market Place paypal integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to integrate Paypal solution to my E-Commerce Project, i did a search and found multiple ways to integrate with paypal, and got confused.

I have multiple sellers (each seller has a store), and their pay-pal accounts (emails), now i want to convert the user to paypal when he press "check out" button, the paypal request should include cart details (items and and prices), shipping cost, shipping address, billing address and seller paypal account (the money should be transferred to the seller paypal account).

So, what is the best paypal solution to apply this, and it will be very helpfully if there are some code samples or tutorials.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you wanting to keep a commission for yourself?

Comment: No, i just want to send money directly to the seller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Express Checkout on the Classic API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#express-checkout).  Specifically, [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/), [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/), and [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/).

You can use the SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID parameter in SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment to specify the account the money should be sent to.  This method will not require any Permissions or anything special to work.  You'll just use your own API credentials, but the money will fall to the account specified.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a PHP guy.